# Are we requiring user registration?

Tags: support, asking-questions, login

Previous [feature](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7897/require-registration-to-ask-a-question) [requests](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7265/169736) about this have been confronted with opposition, yet right now if I try to ask a question, it asks me for a valid email and to verify my account. This struck me odd, because the only reason we were doing that was as means [to slow down spammers](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8085/regarding-the-recent-wave-of-spam-what-are-we-doing-about-it/8086#8086) and I've not seen anything around that would suggest that the change was permanent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we are as a attempt to slow down spammers. The SE team has told us that it's working, and we haven't seen nearly as much spam as we would otherwise.

Comment: Darn! Give a rest will ya, SPAMMERS?!